# Oracle SQL. Find Matching values in two different columns and different rows from same table or different one

Tags: sql, oracle

it is my first question in this community. Any help is welcomed.

Imagine I have a table like this (It can also be having the columns in different tables, I do not mind):

Account_Name_1:

```
Nike                
Pepsi              
Coke
```

Account_Name_2:

```
Reebok
Coke
Nike
```

I need to query a list of Account Names who are in "Account_Name_1" and "Account_Name_2"

Which will result as:

Accounts_in_both_columns

Nike

Coke

How can I do this? I have tried with Inner Join but I am not sure,

Thank you :)

extra:

I also have a problem of naming inconsistency across the Account names, some of them are named differently even if they are the same account. Example:

Account_Name_1     Account_Name_2
**Nike**           Reebok
Pepsi              Coke
Coke               **Nike Inc**

If we run the same query as before, it will only list 'Coke'.

I have read about UTL Matching, Levenshtein Distance Algorithm and JARO_WINKLER_SIMILARITY Function. But I am not able to create a column of those values who has similarity and how much similar are they, so I can investigate and decide if they are the same account or not.

Please keep in mind it is not about same row matching, but value matching in two columns. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `union`:

```
select account_name_1 as account_name
from t
union   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
select account_name_2
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want the values in both columns, just use `exists`:

```
select distinct account_name_1 as account_name
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.account_name_2 = t.account_name_1
             );
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, thank you. With this approach I get a list of all the accounts of both columns in one column. What I need is a list of accounts which are in both columns. Those who are only in one of the columns is not needed. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, it is `intersect` you're looking for:

```
SQL> with
  2  tab_1 (col) as
  3    (select 'Nike'   from dual union all
  4     select 'Pepsi'  from dual union all
  5     select 'Coke'   from dual
  6    ),
  7  tab_2 (col) as
  8    (select 'Reebok' from dual union all
  9     select 'Coke'   from dual union all
 10     select 'Nike'   from dual
 11    )
 12  -- code you need follows
 13  select col from tab_1
 14  intersect
 15  select col from tab_2;

COL
------
Coke
Nike

SQL>
```